# "She does Sinjit" What does this "Sinjit" mean?

Tags: meaning

I found the following word in *English vocabulary in use* book. The lessen describe how to use do / did / done.

> She does **Sinjit**.

What does the *Sinjit* mean?

I couldn't find it in dictionaries.

Comment: I've never heard it before.  The fact that it's capitalized implies that it's a proper name.  Without more context I think it's impossible to say what exactly it is or means.

Comment: @stangdon actually there is no more context, it is an example how to use "do" verb in the book

Comment: ...and without more context, there's no way to know what it means.  It isn't an English word.

Comment: Can it be so that the flash game "Sinjid" is meant here? :) http://sinjid.wikia.com/wiki/Sinjid_Wiki

Comment: The only phrase I could find from that book was "So does Sinjit." Sinjit appears to be a name. https://image.slidesharecdn.com/cambridge-englishvocabularyinuse-elementary-141218131236-conversion-gate01/95/cambridge-english-vocabulary-in-use-elementary-17-638.jpg?cb=1418908669

Comment: Thank you guys, it is my mistake, should I delete the question?

Comment: Was the problem a misprint in the version of the book you were reading? If it was a misprint, this question might be useful to other folks reading the same version.

Comment: @ColleenV actually no, I have been studying since morning,  so it seems I'm tired and I misread it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a misreading ("So does", read as "she does")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably use [this textbook](http://env.humg.edu.vn/attachments/article/179/McCarthy%20(1999).%20English%20Vocab%20in%20Use%20(Elementary).pdf).

Everything is clear now. There is a short answer on page 14:

> So Sinjit does.

and you probably misprinted the original phrase.
The phrase given in the textbook means 'And Sinjit does it, too', so Sinjit is a proper name, indeed.

Comment: The only thing I would add to your answer is that the capitalization of Sinjit is a clue that it is probably a name of something or someone.